# Как возвращать 403 код ответа при просроченном токене Laravel Passport?

Tags: php, laravel, api, oauth2, laravel-8

Пишу api на 8 версии Laravel. Для авторизации был выбран Passport. При отсутствие или неверном токене возвращается 401 код ответа сервера как и надо, но при просрочке токена также возвращается 401 код ответа, что неверно и по идее должен быть 403 токен. Прорыл весь интернет и всю документацию, но так и не нашел ответ на вопрос.

Comment: В [RFC 4679](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-5.2) нет спецификации по поводу того, какой код должен возвращать при просроченном refresh_token сервер, это делается по усмотрению создателя библиотеки. На эту тему много обсуждений и мнений, но конкретно в RFC нет конкретного по этому вопросу и остается на усмотрение библиотеки (имплементации).

Comment: Вы не правы. Правильный код 401. 403 возвращается, если пользователь верный, но ему не хватает прав на доступ к данным. В то время как 401 говорит что пользователь представил неверные аутентификационные данные, коим является токен

Comment: @ArchDemon, спасибо, я сам говорил это сотрудникам, но мы так посчитали кол-во запросов при подходе 401 - проблемы с авторизацией, токен невалидный, а 403 - просто надо обновить пару токенов по случаю истечения срока меньше. Если оставить все так как есть, то есть с всегда 401 кодом, проблем больших с этим не будет, но если вдруг как то можно сделать так как задумали мы, при этом с не очень большой доп. нагрузкой, будет неплохо.

Comment: Мы в своём проекте на java spring возвращаем json с ошибкой. Там указываем сообщение и код ошибки. По этой дополнительной информации можно разделять ошибки протухание токена и не валидного токена, даже если http код приходит один - 401.

Comment: @ArchDemon а вы случайно не знаете как в Passport определить что токен истек? Тоже думал о подобном подходе, но точно так же не нашел информацию по этому поводу как в документации, так же просто "гугля".

Comment: Не работал с laravel и с данной библиотекой в частности

Comment: @ArchDemon все равно благодарю вас за полные и качественные ответы, решение с тем что оставить токен просто в сообщении указывать почему такой код может мне поможет. Еще раз благодарю!